# update empty attributes with select

Tags: php, mysql

```
            $attrib= array('State', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six');              
            for ($i=0; $i <6; $i++) { 
                $sql= "insert into table(Attribute, col1, col2)
                select '$attrib[$i]', MIN(cast(".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1))), MAX(cast(".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1))) from table2";
                $run_sql= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            }

            for ($i=0; $i < 6; $i++) { 
                $sql= "insert into table(col3, col4)
                select MIN(cast(".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1))),  MAX(cast(".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1))) from table2 where Class=1";
                $run_sql= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            }
```

The problem in here is that the second for loop starts insertion into col3 and col4 where the insertion of col1 and col2 ends. So the starting all the values of col3 and col4 are empty i want to update those empty values instead of starting insertion where the values of col1 and col2 ends.

Comment: Do you have any `primary key` in `table2` table?

Comment: @EhsanT no i dont have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had a `Primary Key` for you table `table2`, it would be better, but since your subqueries return only one row, the you still can combine these two queries in one query like this:

```
$sql = "insert into table(Attribute, col1, col2, col3, col4)
select t2_1.".$attrib[$i].", MIN(cast(t2_1.".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1))), MAX(cast(t2_1.".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1))), MIN(cast(t2_2.".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1))),  MAX(cast(t2_2.".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1)))
from table2 as t2_1, table2 as t2_2
where t2_2.Class = 1";
```

I'm joining these two table(which both are the same `table2`) and I'm giving them alias names `t2_1` and `t2_2`(you can change these two names with any other name which make more sense to you) and I'm selecting fields that I want from each of them.

So your code would have only one loop and look like this:

```
$attrib = array('State', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six');              
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($attrib); $i++) { 
    $sql = "insert into table(Attribute, col1, col2, col3, col4)
    select t2_1.".$attrib[$i].", MIN(cast(t2_1.".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1))), MAX(cast(t2_1.".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1))), MIN(cast(t2_2.".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1))),  MAX(cast(t2_2.".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1)))
    from table2 as t2_1, table2 as t2_2
    where t2_2.Class = 1";
    $run_sql= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

Also note that in you `for`, instead of using a hardcode number **6** it's better to your `count()` to get the length of the array(as I'm using in this code) and since you have 7 records in your array, I think your `for` loop condition should be `<=` instead of `<`

Comment: Your code was like this, I can change it for you, So please tell me, you want the value of `Attribute` field always be the value of `State` field?

Comment: Solved it Thanks.

Comment: sorry for interrupting you again. what if i do it for the class=0. i am repeating the code and giving it name t2_3 and at the last add the condition with t2_3.Class=0. but it's not inserting anything not even the previous records which works fine without adding this code.

Comment: What to you mean by saying _what if i do it for the class=0_? if you want to change `class=1` to `class=0` just change it, but if not, please elaborate on how do you want to add the new condition?

Comment: `$sql = "insert into range_table(Attribute, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
        select '$attrib[$i]', MIN(cast(t2_1.".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1))), MAX(cast(t2_1.".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1))), MIN(cast(t2_2.".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1))),  MAX(cast(t2_2.".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1))), MIN(cast(t2_3.".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1))),  MAX(cast(t2_3.".$attrib[$i]." as decimal(5,1)))
        from table2 as t2_1, table2 as t2_2
        where t2_2.Class = 1, table2 as t2_3
        where t2_3.Class = 0";`

Comment: OK, then just move `table2 as t2_3 ` to `from` clause. like this: `from table2 as t2_1, table2 as t2_2, table2 as t2_3`

Comment: Then where to put where conditions. as t2_2 and t2_3 have different conditions.

Comment: `from table2 as t2_1, table2 as t2_2, table2 as t2_3 where t2_2.Class = 1 and t2_3.Class = 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129147/discussion-between-tooba-and-ehsant).